# Pass res.data from one post request to different React component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have created a login form in React that uses an Axios post request like this:

```
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/users/validate', {
            email: email,
            password: password,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            setError(res.data);

            //If validation passed
            if (res.data.includes('Login successful')) {
                navigate('/');
            };
        });
```

I would like to pass the `res.data` from this post request to a different React component. Specifically being the Header component so I can display the text from `res.data`.

This is the structure of the components in my React app

```
    <>
      <Header />
      
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Index />}/>
        <Route path="/results/:id" element={<Results />} /> {/* Passes route with ID from input */}
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register /> } />        
        <Route path="/users" element={<Users />}/>
        <Route path="/products" element={<Products />}/>
        <Route path="*" element={<Error />}/>
      </Routes>

      <Footer />

    </>
```

With `Login` being the component containing the `res.data` and Header being the component I would like to send `res.data` too.

Ill include the back-end for in case their is a method to send this to that component from the back-end but ideally I would like to do it through the front-end perhaps using an axios request.

```
        app.post('/users/validate', (req, res) => {
            const email = req.body.email;
            const password = req.body.password;
            if (email && password) {
                //Check all emails against input
                db.query(selectEmail, [email], (err, rows) => { 
                    if (err) throw err;
                    if (rows.length > 0) {
                        //If password and email match then login
                        if (HashPassword(password, rows[0].salt) == rows[0].password) { //Checks password and compares to hash
                            res.send(rows[0].first_name);
                        }
                        else {
                            res.send('Incorrect password');
                        };
                    }
    
                    else {
                        res.send('Email or password are incorrect');
                    };
                });
            };
        });
```

In a simplified version I want to send the `first_name` row from my back end to the `Header` component on my front-end. But I am struggling to understand how to do this because the post request containing `first_name` is found under is currently being used under the `Login` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about passing with the `state` prop in [useNavigate - hook](https://beta.reactrouter.com/en/dev/hooks/use-navigate) as

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost:8080/users/validate", {
    email: email,
    password: password,
  })
  .then((res) => {
    setError(res.data);

    //If validation passed
    if (res.data.includes("Login successful")) {
      navigate("/", {state: res.data}); // like so
    }
  });
```

and In `Header` component you can get the value using [useLocation hook](https://beta.reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location)

Comment: This worked I was able to pass this to my other component using `useEffect(() => {setUsername(location.state);}, [location]); `

Answer (score 0):

You should use a state management library like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) or [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

With the state management library, you can access your state in all the components of your app.

Comment: I have used context before but seeing as this was a one time pass I didn't see the need